# Как пометить тип дочернего класса

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Есть такой код. И я не могу понять, как описать JSDoc'ом тип дочернего класса. То есть, у метода `Model.find` не получается описать, что этот метод возвращает ту модель, которая является текущим контекстом этого метода в момент вызова.

Как результат IDE не может автокомплитить свойства класса `Cat` и предлагает только свойства класса `Model` (в моём случае).

```js
// Базовая модель
class Model {

  /**
   * @return {Model}
   */
  static find() {
    /* как-то ищет модель и возвращает её */
  }
}

// Дочерняя модель
class Cat extends Model {}

// Собираюсь использовать это так

const cat = Cat.find();

// разумеется в переменной cat будет экземпляр класса Cat, а не Model
```

Хотелось бы написать, что то типа `self` или т.п. Ни кто не знает как это можно оформить?